# What does this table mean in the context of an ADC

Tags: analog, adc, gain

I found this [ADC](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads112c04.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1684524837285). I came across these noise tables.

My questions:

1. In Table 1 how are the paratheses values (uVpp) calculated?
2. From Table 2 what do those values mean in practical terms?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> In Table 1 how are the paratheses values (uVpp) calculated

By adding up all the internal noise sources. Resistance and silicon can all create noise sources. If the noise sources before the amplifier the noise will be amplified by the amplifier (or PGA). [Analog circuits: world class designs](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2425148.Analog_Circuits) shows how this is done (I would describe more here but it's about a chapter to describe)

> From Table 2 what do those values mean in practical terms?

It means that if you grounded the inputs that's how many bits of noise you would see. When there's a decimal involved it means that on average that so many bits of noise you'll see over a certain time. So if you were looking at the lowest bit if you set the PGA to 128 you would start to see a few noisy bits

Comment: I thought Table 2 would mean how bits the ADC will actually be for the respective noise value. So for example at a gain of 128 and SPS of 45, the ADC would no longer be seen as a 16-bit ADC but rather a 15.78-bit ADC.

Comment: Yep, you'll see some noisy bits at the higher gains. That's also assuming that you have grounded input the noise from your analog system will also increase the amount of noisy bits. The more noise you have the less SNR you will have